# deleting lines from jsonl file with matching key/value using jq

Tags: json, jq, jsonlines

I have a large jsonl file like so:

```
# source.jsonl
{"id": "y88979", "content": "content goes here"}
{"id": "h93794", "content": "content goes here"}
{"id": "k9489", "content": "content goes here"}
{"id": "p48947", "content": "content goes here"}
{"id": "i8408", "content": "content goes here"}
```

I have a banned id list like so:

```
#banned_list.txt
k9489
p48947
</snip>
```

I want to now delete the lines where the "id" matches any of the id on the banned list text file. So I am looking for the result:

```
{"id": "y88979", "content": "content goes here"}
{"id": "h93794", "content": "content goes here"}
{"id": "i8408", "content": "content goes here"}
```

Python would be too slow to iterate over this jsonl file (20gb) and I see that `jq` is the best for doing this but unsure about the syntax which will allow it to take all ids from a list.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the banned ids using `--rawfile`, split it at newline characters, and compare each JSON line read if its `.id` is contained:

```bash
jq -c --rawfile b banned_list.txt 'select(IN(.id; $b | (. / "\n")[]) | not)' source.jsonl
```

This, however, would split the list of banned ids over and over on each input line, so it'd be better to prepare it beforehand into a proper JSON array using another call to jq, and `--slurpfile` to read the JSON strings into an array:

```bash
jq -c --slurpfile b <(jq -R . banned_list.txt) 'select(IN(.id; $b[]) | not)' source.jsonl
```

Output:

```json
{"id":"y88979","content":"content goes here"}
{"id":"h93794","content":"content goes here"}
{"id":"i8408","content":"content goes here"}
```

You could even improve on this by sorting the list of banned ids, and use `bsearch` for a binary search.

Comment: insane answer thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I will explain how implement a blacklist (your interest) and a whitelist:

```
$ cat banned_list.txt
k9489
p48947
```

You can create a simple json-list : (Note: the awk ensures no '\r' chars ):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\r/,"",$0);print $0}' banned_list.txt  | jq --raw-input '.' | jq '.' -s > list.json

$ cat list.json
[
  "k9489",
  "p48947"
]
```

Blacklist implementation:

Select all objects with the ".id" not in the $ban array.
Here we read list.json into "black" jq-variable:

```
$ jq --argfile black list.json 'select(.id|IN($black[])|not) ' source.jsonl -c
{"id":"y88979","content":"content goes here"}
{"id":"h93794","content":"content goes here"}
{"id":"i8408","content":"content goes here"}
```

Whitelist implementation:

Select all objects with the ".id" in the $ban array.
Here we read list.json into "white" jq-variable:

```
$ jq --argfile white list.json 'select(.id|IN($white[])) ' source.jsonl -c
{"id":"k9489","content":"content goes here"}
{"id":"p48947","content":"content goes here"}
```